# MigraDoc PDF renderer encounters System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, azure, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using MigraDoc and PDF renderer on Azure and it is throwing up a System.NullReferenceException. This is the exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at PdfSharp.Fonts.OpenType.OpenTypeFontface.CetOrCreateFrom(XFontSource fontSource)
at PdfSharp.Drawing.XGlyphTypeface.GetOrCreateFrom(String familyName, FontResolvingOptions fontResolvingOptions)
at PdfSharp.Drawing.XFont.Initialize()
at MigraDoc.Rendering.FontHandler.FontToXFont(Font font, PdfFontEncoding encoding)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.ParagraphRenderer.get_CurrentFont()
at MigraDoc.Rendering.ParagraphRenderer.InitFormat(Area area, FormatInfo previousFormatInfo)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.ParagraphRenderer.Format(Area area, FormatInfo previousFormatInfo)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.TopDownFormatter.FormatOnAreas(XGraphics gfx, Boolean topLevel)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.FormattedDocument.Format(XGraphics gfx)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer.PrepareDocument()
at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.PrepareDocumentRenderer(Boolean prepareCompletely)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.PrepareRenderPages()
at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.RenderDocument()
at EmailQueue.AddCopyToEFolder.<Run>d__3.MoveNext()
```

This is the code I'm using at the point of issue. `document` is of class MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Document and has been filled in with text.

```
PdfDocumentRenderer pdf = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
pdf.Document = document;
pdf.RenderDocument(); //<-- This is where the exception occurs
pdf.Save(stream, false);
```

Edit: I have since implemented a MyFontResolver class as follows and I am using GlobalFontSettings.FontResolver = new MyFontResolver(); in my code to set the font resolver as the class

```
public class MyFontResolver : IFontResolver
    {
        public FontResolverInfo ResolveTypeface(string familyName, bool isBold, bool isItalic)
        {
            // Ignore case of font names.
            var name = familyName.ToLower();

            // Deal with the fonts we know.
            switch (name)
            {
                case "ubuntu":
                    if (isBold)
                    {
                        if (isItalic)
                            return new FontResolverInfo("Ubuntu#bi");
                        return new FontResolverInfo("Ubuntu#b");
                    }
                    if (isItalic)
                        return new FontResolverInfo("Ubuntu#i");
                    return new FontResolverInfo("Ubuntu#");

                case "janitor":
                    return new FontResolverInfo("Janitor#");
            }

            // We pass all other font requests to the default handler.
            // When running on a web server without sufficient permission, you can return a default font at this stage.
            return PlatformFontResolver.ResolveTypeface(familyName, isBold, isItalic);
        }

        private byte[] LoadFontData(string name)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            // Test code to find the names of embedded fonts - put a watch on "ourResources"
            //var ourResources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
            {
                if (stream == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("No resource with name " + name);

                int count = (int)stream.Length;
                byte[] data = new byte[count];
                stream.Read(data, 0, count);
                return data;
            }
        }

        public byte[] GetFont(string faceName)
        {
            switch (faceName)
            {
                case "Arial#":
                    return LoadFontData("MyProject.fonts.arial.arial.ttf"); ;

                case "Arial#b":
                    return LoadFontData("MyProject.fonts.arial.arialbd.ttf"); ;

                case "Arial#i":
                    return LoadFontData("MyProject.fonts.arial.ariali.ttf");

                case "Arial#bi":
                    return LoadFontData("MyProject.fonts.arial.arialbi.ttf");
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am now getting a seperate error which I thought my font resolver was supposed to fix

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft Azure returns STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000022L) from GetFontData. This is a bug in Azure. You must implement a FontResolver to circumvent this issue.
at PdfSharp.Drawing.XFontSource.ReadFontBytesFromGdi(Font gdiFont)
at PdfSharp.Fonts.PlatformFontResolver.CreateFontSource(String familyName, FontResolvingOptions fontResolvingOptions, Font& font, String typefaceKey)
at PdfSharp.Fonts.PlatformFontResolver.ResolveTypeface(String familyName, FontResolvingOptions fontResolvingOptions, String typefaceKey)
at PdfSharp.Fonts.PlatformFontResolver.ResolveTypeface(String familyName, Boolean isBold, Boolean isItalic)
at EmailQueue.AddCopyToEFolder.MyFontResolver.ResolveTypeface(String familyName, Boolean isBold, Boolean isItalic)
at PdfSharp.Fonts.FontFactory.ResolveTypeface(String familyName, FontResolvingOptions fontResolvingOptions, String typefaceKey)
at PdfSharp.Drawing.XGlyphTypeface.GetOrCreateFrom(String familyName, FontResolvingOptions fontResolvingOptions)
at PdfSharp.Drawing.XFont.Initialize()
at MigraDoc.Rendering.FontHandler.FontToXFont(Font font, PdfFontEncoding encoding)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.ParagraphRenderer.get_CurrentFont()
at MigraDoc.Rendering.ParagraphRenderer.InitFormat(Area area, FormatInfo previousFormatInfo)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.ParagraphRenderer.Format(Area area, FormatInfo previousFormatInfo)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.TopDownFormatter.FormatOnAreas(XGraphics gfx, Boolean topLevel)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.FormattedDocument.Format(XGraphics gfx)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.DocumentRenderer.PrepareDocument()
at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.PrepareDocumentRenderer(Boolean prepareCompletely)
at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.PrepareRenderPages()
at MigraDoc.Rendering.PdfDocumentRenderer.RenderDocument()
at EmailQueue.AddCopyToEFolder.<Run>d__3.MoveNext()
```

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: Pay attention to the comment "// When running on a web server without sufficient permission, you can return a default font at this stage." in the code you are showing above...

Comment: You wrote on the PDFsharp forum that you solved this issue, but you didn't share how you solved it. Sharing the solution might help others who find this question here. https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=12413#p12413

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if you have to use the `IFontResolver` interface for the fonts you are using in your document.

Most likely your app doesn't have the privileges to access the TTF files installed on the Azure server or the required TTFs are not installed.

See also:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3244
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3073

***Edit:*** To answer the edited question: Your font resolver passes all unhandled requests to `PlatformFontResolver.ResolveTypeface(familyName, isBold, isItalic);` which obviously does not work on Azure. So replace this call with an Exception and make sure your code runs on your local machine without throwing that exception - then it should also run on Azure.

Comment: I believe I've already added the IFontResolver interface. Is there any documentation on how to check the privileges for the ttf files? I've never added them to azure before the links you provided didn't seem to list them. I just added them to the project but I'm not sure if they're on the azure server

Comment: No TTF files will be accessed when the `IFontResolver` is used properly. Can't tell that from your code snippet. But most likely `IFontResolver` is not used properly and therefore you get the System exception.